# When trying to install pg gem: Brew bad interpreter error and not existing ruby version

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, installation, homebrew

I've really made something wrong when re-installing ruby, rails, xcode etc. (maybe even I've deleted my system Ruby installation :/ ) Here's what I have now:

System: OSX 10.8.2 (64-bit)

`which ruby` gives me `/usr/local/bin/ruby`

I have installed `ruby 1.9.3p286`, `Rails 3.2.8` and `rvm 1.16.17 (stable)`

I've installed Ruby and Rails by going with this tips: *http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard*

Next I wanted to run `gem install pg` but I've got an error: `No such file or directory - brew --prefix`

I've tried hit just the `brew` command but I've got another error: `/usr/local/bin/brew: bad interpreter: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin: no such file or directory`

So there is my question (I have installed brew earlier) - why it points on this path of 1.8 Ruby if I don't have this version of Ruby installed? Can I somehow change this path to my current one with ruby(that from which ruby command?)? How fix this brew error? Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I got it - I've edited the file: `/usr/local/bin/brew` and edited ther (first line) the path: from `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin` to `/usr/local/bin/ruby/` and it works now..

Anyone knows how to change default system Ruby path to this one? (to avoid problems with other programs in the future).

Comment: A slightly more portable answer is to use `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` since this will determine which ruby to use dynamically from `$PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

That didn't work for me but it set me on the right track..... I had to do this:

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/ruby /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby`

(and make the bin directory before hand)